# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following piece of code for which i am getting [`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

```
//divides ACode by 10 as many times as specified by the DecimalDigitPosition 
public static int getDecimalDigit(int ACode, int decimalDigitPosition) {
    if (decimalDigitPosition == 0)
        return ACode;
    else {
        ACode = ACode / (10 * decimalDigitPosition);
        int remainder = ACode % 10;
        return remainder;
    }
}
```

I am suspecting this line...

```
digit[i] = getDecimalDigit(samples[i].getValue(), 0);
```

in the code below which could be the reason for this exception.

```
//start a method to decode the message.
public static void decodeMessage(String filename) {
    Sound s = new Sound(filename);
    SoundSample[] samples = s.getSamples();
    int[] digit = new int[3];
    String message = "";
    int sampleIndex = 0;
    boolean nullReached = false;
    while (!nullReached) {
        int asciiValue = 0;
        for (int i = sampleIndex; i < sampleIndex + 3; i++) {
            if (i < samples.length) {
                // this line could be the cause of error..
                digit[i] = getDecimalDigit(samples[i].getValue(), 0);
                asciiValue += digit[i - sampleIndex] * (((i - sampleIndex) == 0) 
                ? 1 
                : ((i - sampleIndex) * 10));
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    digit[j] = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (digit[0] == digit[1] 
        && digit[1] == digit[2] 
        && digit[2] == 0) 
        nullReached = true;
        message += (char) asciiValue;
    }
}
```

#### Stack trace:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at
>   project.decodeMessage(project.java:107) at
>   project.main(project.java:33) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)
>   >

Comment: What lines throw these errors? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: If you think that the problem is due to a certain section of the code, it is usually best just to include that part :)

Comment: Here is the error code: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at project.decodeMessage(project.java:107)
at project.main(project.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
>

Comment: and Tyler, you're right haha I'm not thinking. Editing code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely here in your `decodeMessage` method. I've snipped out some code to isolate the problem:

```
int[] digit = new int[3];
while (!nullReached)
{
    for (int i = sampleIndex; i < sampleIndex + 3; i++)
    {
        if (i < samples.length)
        {
            digit[i] = getDecimalDigit(samples[i].getValue(), 0);   // This should be the line that throws the exception                
        }               
    }           
    sampleIndex += 3;           
}
```

The second time through your `while` loop, `sampleIndex` will be `3`, so `i` will start at `3`. Then you try to dereference `digit[i]`, which would be `digit[3]`. Since `digit[]` is an `int[3]`, then `digit[3]` is out of the bounds of the array.

Maybe you want to do this instead:

```
digit[i-sampleIndex] = getDecimalDigit(samples[i].getValue(), 0);
```

Comment: Ok so the error was where I was thinking it was. How do I go about editing this? I'm thinking possibly changing the int value of 3 or the sampleIndex value?

Comment: I edited my answer to give a possible solution. I can't run the code and I haven't taken the time to try to understand what it's doing, so I don't know for sure that my solution will produce the behavior you want, but it should eliminate the OOB exception.

Comment: My code is trying to decode an audio file with a text message hidden inside of it. The fix you provided allows the code the compile and execute correctly! But it garbles (garbles the text similar to dingbats font) the message instead of showing the text.